# A diffeomorphism with $\det(df)>0$ and convexity of matrices

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a diffeomorphism such that $\det(df)>0$ at the origin (hence everywhere). Show that there is a continuous map $F: [0,1]\times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that for each $t\in [0, 1]$, $F(t, \cdot)$ is a diffeomorphism, $F(0, x)=Id, F(1, x)=f(x)$.

The hint is to use the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is linearly contractible.

So this reduces to showing that $\det((1-t)df+tI)>0$. Here, I get stuck. At first I thought maybe there is some well known convexity relation that could be useful, but then I realized if I take the map $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots, x_n)\to (-x_1, -x_2, x_3, \ldots x_n)$, it has $\det(df)>0$ but when $t=1/2$ $\det((1/2)df+(1/2)I)=0$, so the above idea fails.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Gl_n^+$ is connected, up to a translation and a rotation I may suppose $f(0)=0$ and $df(0)=I$.

Now, for $t>0$ define
$$F_t(x)=f(tx)/t$$
and
$$F_0(x)=x$$

Since $df(0)=I=F_0$, $F$ is continuous, $dF_t(x)=df(tx)>0$ for every $t$, $F_1=f$ and $F_0=I$, we have finished.

Comment: Sorry, but why can we assume $df(0)=I$?

Comment: Just make a linear change of coordinates on $\Bbb R^n$ by $df(0)^{-1}$.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't quite see why $F_{t}$ as defined above is continous.

Comment: Well, it's certainly continuous at $(x,t)$ for $t\ne 0$. For $x$ fixed, it's continuous at $t=0$ by the definition of directional derivative. But, in fact, by the definition of the derivative of a map on $\Bbb R^n$, given $\epsilon>0$ we have $\delta>0$ so that $$\|f(tx)-df_0(tx)\|<\epsilon\|tx\|$$ for $\|tx\|<\delta$, which means that $$\|F_t(x)-F_0(x)\|<\epsilon\|x\|<\epsilon$$ for $(x,t)$ close to $(0,0)$.

Comment: @Ted Thanks! Your proof of continuity is perfect. Anyway, to suppose $df(0)=I$, it's not enough to make a change of coordinates by $df(0)^{-1}$: you have to change coordinates continuously, so you need a path between $df(0)^{-1}$ and $I$ in $Gl_n^+$. You *have* to use the fact that $Gl_n^+$ is connected.

Comment: Indeed, @GiulioBresciani. My sloppiness.